# Call native function Synchronously

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I was using `Phonegap Plugins` for calling my Objective C function from Java Script.

But from the source code as seen on the svn it seems that the asynchronous behavior(callback function) is actually iPhone's native way of handling the calls.

Is there a way in which I can make a synchronous call from my JS in iOS-iPhone/iPad Application?

my JS should do something like the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myfunc(){

    var ret = CallMyObjCFunction();

    alert(ret);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything needs to be asynchronous. You send the result of your function back to Javascript in a CDVPluginResult.

Your javascript might looks something more like

```
function myfunc(){

    function success(result) {
        alert(result);
    }

    function fail() {
        alert("There was a problem");
    }

    cordova.exec(success, fail, "YourPlugin", "CallMyObjCFunction", [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  No such synchronous call appears to exist in the iOS public APIs.